# d3.scale.linear() not working

Tags: javascript, d3.js

I am using d3.scale.linear() to scale input domain to an output range. I looked at this documentation

```
http://alignedleft.com/tutorials/d3/scales
```

and have this so far

```
//here I am declaring the domain and range by passing the max, min as parameters
    var rScale = d3.scale.linear()
        .domain('min', 'max')
        .range('10', '250');
```

I am pre calculating the max and min and storing them in variables and passing those variables as parameters to the domain and range

Then I am just passing the rScale as a parameter to the attribute to the circle as `.attr('r',rScale)`

Cant seem to figure out what I am doing wrong

Here is my fiddle

http://jsfiddle.net/sghoush1/Vn7mf/19/

Comment: In version 4 of d3 use ```d3.scaleLinear()``` instead of ```d3.scale.linear()```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1) To pass in a domain and range to a scale, use an array:

```
    var rScale = d3.scale.linear()
    .domain([min, max])
    .range([10, 250]);
```

2) To use your scale:

```
   .attr("r", function(d) { return rScale(d.consumption_gj_);})
```

Answer (score 4):

Pass domain and range as an array.

```
D3 v3 uses:-
-------------
var rscale = d3.scale.linear()
             .domain([min,max])
             .range([10,300])

D3 v4:-
-----------
var rscale = d3.scaleLinear()
             .domain([min,max])
             .range([10,300])
```